# Cannot override Hardhat Timeout of 40000ms

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat

**Issue**: I cannot override the default timeout of 40000ms when testing using rinkeby network. I'm getting the error of *Timeout of 40000ms exceeded*. (Error: Timeout of 40000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise,...) I didn't test with other json-rpc network such as kovan so I can't be certain the issue is present there too

**Background**: my solidity code is a simple lottery setup and is connected to chainlink oracle to determine usd/eth exchange. I can confirm my solidity code is fine because the test sometimes run fine and is able to return me those values I have consoled.log. Other time, it just give a *timeout error*

unless the way I setup my test is incorrect, then I think the issue lies in the timeout.  Anyone can advise on this? Thanks

**Packages**
"hardhat": "^2.8.2", 
"@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "^2.0.4", 
"@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle": "^2.0.1",
"chai": "^4.3.4",

```
networks: {
    rinkeby: {
      url: INFURA_RINKEBY_URL,
      accounts: [
        `0x${PRIVATE_KEY_RINKEBY}`,
        `0x${TESTNET_ACCOUNT_1}`,
        `0x${TESTNET_ACCOUNT_2}`,
      ],
      timeout: 200000,  // <---- issue
    }
  },

describe.only("Lottery", function () {
  let lottery;
  let admin;
  let player1;
  let player2;
  let result;

  before(async () => {
    const Lottery = await ethers.getContractFactory("Lottery");
    lottery = await Lottery.deploy();
    await lottery.deployed();

    [admin, player1, player2] = await ethers.getSigners();

    await lottery.connect(admin).startLottery();

    await lottery.connect(player1).enter({
      value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.1"),
    });

    // await lottery.connect(player2).enter({
    //   value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.1"),
    // });
  });

  describe.only("Return Lottery Results", async function () {
    it("Should return lottery", async function () {
      console.log("fee", await lottery.fee());
      console.log("usdEntryFee", await lottery.usdEntryFee());
      //todo function call to a non-contract account
      console.log("getEntranceFee", await lottery.getEntranceFee());
      console.log("randomness", await lottery.randomness());
      console.log("lottery_state", await lottery.lottery_state());
      console.log("players", await lottery.getPlayers());
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: maybe you need to change the mocha timeout in hardhat config file   mocha: {
    timeout: <time in milli second>,
  },

Answer (score 11):

setting mocha timeout helped in my case (in hardhat.config.js)

```
module.exports = {
...
  mocha: {
    timeout: 100000000
  },
...
}
```

Comment: Not possible to set in the test? I onlyhave one of 100 tests which need a timeout over 40MM ms

Answer (score 3):

Example of increasing timeout for a particular test:

```
    it('test ...', async function () {
        .....
    }).timeout(1000000);
```